# How to reserve physical memory from RISC-V Linux (Zedboard)?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, riscv

I want to reserve a portion of physical memory when booting Linux.
With default RISC-V kernel running on a Zedboard, I saw the size of physical memory was 254MB (0xfe00000 bytes, 260096K):

```
       INSTRUCTION SETS WANT TO BE FREE
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.14.33-g043bb5d (guanglin@guanglin-a11-linux) (gcc version 5.2.5
[    0.000000] Detected 0xfe00000 bytes of physical memory
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 64135
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/htifblk0
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
[    0.000000] Memory: 253568K/260096K available (1722K kernel code, 124K rwdata, 356K rodata)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:2
[    0.150000] Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 20.01 BogoMIPS (lpj=100072)
[    0.150000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.150000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.150000] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.150000] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.150000] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.150000] Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.150000] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
[    0.150000] TCP: reno registered
[    0.150000] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.150000] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.150000] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
[    0.150000] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.150000] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.170000] htifcon htif1: detected console
[    0.170000] console [htifcon0] enabled
[    0.170000] htifblk htif2: detected disk
[    0.170000] htifblk htif2: added htifblk0
[    0.170000] TCP: cubic registered
[    0.180000] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) readonly on device 254:0.
[    0.180000] devtmpfs: mounted
[    0.180000] Freeing unused kernel memory: 68K (ffffffff80000000 - ffffffff80011000)
```

So I try to reserve 126MB of physical memory by providing kernel parameters "mem=128M memmap=126M$128M", but the physical memory size Linux sees is still the same.

```
    INSTRUCTION SETS WANT TO BE FREE
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.14.33-g043bb5d (guanglin@guanglin-a11-linux) (gcc version 5.2.5
[    0.000000] Detected 0xfe00000 bytes of physical memory
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00200000-0x0fffffff]
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 64135
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: root=/dev/htifblk0 mem=128M memmap=126M$128M
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Sorting __ex_table...
[    0.000000] Memory: 253568K/260096K available (1722K kernel code, 124K rwdata, 356K rodata)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:2
[    0.150000] Calibrating delay using timer specific routine.. 20.01 BogoMIPS (lpj=100068)
[    0.150000] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.150000] Mount-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.150000] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.150000] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.150000] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.150000] Switched to clocksource riscv_clocksource
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.150000] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.150000] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
[    0.150000] TCP: reno registered
[    0.150000] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.150000] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.150000] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.150000] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 6144 bytes)
[    0.150000] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.150000] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.170000] htifcon htif1: detected console
[    0.170000] console [htifcon0] enabled
[    0.170000] htifblk htif2: detected disk
[    0.170000] htifblk htif2: added htifblk0
[    0.170000] TCP: cubic registered
[    0.180000] VFS: Mounted root (ext2 filesystem) readonly on device 254:0.
[    0.180000] devtmpfs: mounted
[    0.180000] Freeing unused kernel memory: 68K (ffffffff80000000 - ffffffff80011000)
/ #
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is by reserving memory? Do you want linux to not know it exists? Reserving it for a device may actually require a driver: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/how-can-i-reserve-a-block-of-memory-from-the-linux-kernel

Comment: My goal is to reserve a contiguous physical memory region for hardware accelerator. My user space program must have access to this region too (to load input data into the memory and get output data from the memory). Thanks!

Comment: So if linux is going to give user-space access, what is wrong with linux seeing that memory at boot?

Comment: The reason is that I want to control which physical memory region (aka. physical address region) to be reserved so I can potentially control which memory controller to be used for my accelerator. If Linux sees the memory at boot and allocates them as unmovable pages, I won't be able to do that. Thanks!